# Adding presence indicator to a custom web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have a custom web part which is generating some user data.  I have added the appropriate code to output the standard presence icon and menu however this is acting rather stangely.

The rendered html of my web part is as follows:

```
<span>  
   <a href="http://mysite/Person.aspx?accountname=USERID">USERNAME</a>&nbsp;   
   <img border="0" height="12" width="12" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" onload="IMNRC('USEREMAIL')" id="imnUSERID" ShowOfflinePawn="1" />  
</span>
```

Obviously replacing USERID, USERNAME, USEREMAIL etc.

The problems are twofold.

1) In IE7 the presence information does not get retrieved.  The menu displays correctly but the icon does not appear and when you hover over the gap the drop down menu does not provide IM settings.

2) In IE8 RC1 the presence information comes back correctly and the icon displays, but the drop down list is rendered severeal inches above the icon. ([see this screenshot](http://twitpic.com/1z4r9))

Any help with these issues, or with other tips about adding presence to custom web parts would be greatfully received.

#### Update on progress

*- Adding web page to 'Trusted Sites' for IE7 - did nothing
 - Compatability view for IE8 makes no difference.
 - Changed to id="CSRP_id,type=sip"
Changed code to the following on recommendation:*

```
<span>     
<img class="PresenceImage" src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="IMNRC('USEREMAIL')" name="imnmark" ShowOfflinePawn="1" id="contact_im,type=sip" />     
</span>
```

*None of the above updates have been succesful.*

Comment: I cannot tell, but is the img ID tag a constant, or are you creating these dynamically. (have had issue with constant ID's, but cannot tell if it is the same thing)

Comment: No that is id fixed though I have also tried with dynamic id based on the userID and that did not work correctly either.

Comment: I noticed using a fixed ID that only the first item on a page would be updated with the persons details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are going to have to eliminate whether you have a styling issue or a javascript issue.

If all of your presence bubbles display correctly, then get the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) and try and trace the css back. Even change the themes of the site and see if you get a different result.

This is our html, which works nice

```
 <span>
 <img width="12" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" onload="IMNRC('[USERMAIL]')" id="IMID[GUID]" ShowOfflinePawn=1 alt="Presence bubble">[USERNAME]</span>
```

Note:

[USERMAIL] = obvious
[USERNAME] = obvious
[GUID] = random guid

**Also note the malformed img tag** with no end "/>" (just ">"). We use this as this is the html generated by SharePoint (please don't get me started on *that*).

Comment: Thanks Nat, I notice that you are using a slightly different technique again.  Do you recommend then that I adjust my html to use the old html 4 style unclosed img tag?

Comment: It is hard to know. I am not really a specialist in css vs browsers, give it a shot and see what works.

Comment: FYI, I was having issues with indicator rendering (the indicator appeared when I hovered over any element in the web part) -- enclosing the `IMG` inside a `SPAN`, as shown above, fixed my problem.

No insight into the original post's problem; the HTML looks identical to mine and it renders fine in IE7/8.